# ssh and scp fails to transfer file

Tags: shell, ssh, amazon-ec2, scp

I'm trying to copy a file from my local machine to an EC2 instance. If I do

```
ssh <hostname>
```

everything works fine. I also checked that there are enough disk space on destination machine, and I have write permission. Now when I do

```
scp file <hostname>:
```

I get a `Write failed: Broken pipe` error. I tried doing `scp -vvv`, but everything looked normal up until the error. The strange thing is that if I check the destination machine, EXACTLY 32768 bytes were copied. Also if I try

```
<file ssh <hostname> "cat > file"
```

This time EXACTLY 16384 bytes get copied, and fails with the same error. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Copying files smaller than 32K works just fine.

Comment: Assuming Linux, is there any chance you are out of inodes on the drive? This will show up as space available but you won't be able to create a file. You can check with `df -i`.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. The AWS instance is running RHEL. No obvious reason why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

SCP does not handle retries. If there was a connection problem, the upload would be cut off. As the problem is recurring, the issue may not be a connection problem, but still.

Try SFTP instead.

Answer (score 0):

See if the remote filesystem is full or almost full. If the remote system is linux or unix, then this would tell you how full that particular filesystem is:

```
ssh <hostname> 'df .'
```

Comment: Your answer worked. I looked on the remote server and the disk was at 100%...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

scp write failure.
Login to server that you want to copy too.
check the root disk space. df -h
In my case low disk space on / was the cause.